# Removing a record from a bulk collection in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

I loop through a set of transactions and bulk collect the transaction ids to a variable. After that there is a part that I have to check for some conditions. If it fails for one transaction I want to remove it from my bulk collection and should proceed only with the correct ones. Is there a way to achieve it in plsql? I tried the possibility of using 'savepoint'. But did not receive any positive output.

Comment: You can use `your_collection.DELETE(index_of_item);` And if some more specific answer needed: [mre] would be helpful here.

Comment: ```MULTISET EXCEPT ``` could also work but without any sample data it's hard to answer your question

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "proceed only with the correct ones".. or how you tried to use a savepoint. Please show us some code.